# JPQL - Update with Multiple where conditions

Tags: java, hibernate, hql, where-clause, jpql

Does JPQL support the following Update?

```
Update Person p set p.name = :name_1 where p.id = :id_1,
                    p.name = :name_2 where p.id = :id_2,
                    p.name = :name_3 where p.id = :id_3
```

If not, are there any alternatives? 
I tried it myself. But `createQuery` returned null.

Comment: No I don't think, you need 3 JPA updates for 3 SQL updates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Case expression is supported in JPA 2.0. I have provided pseudo-code, can make modifications accordingly.

- You can try below JPQL query using `CASE`.

  `Update Person p set p.name = CASE WHEN (p.id = :id1) THEN :name_1 WHEN (p.id = :id2) THEN :name_2 WHEN (p.id = :id3) THEN :name_3 END`

  > general_case_expression::= CASE WHEN conditional_expression THEN
  >   scalar_expression ELSE scalar_expression END
- Else, can try Criteria API to build the query.

  > when(Expression condition, R result) : Add a
  >   when/then clause to the case expression.

  `criteriaBuilder.selectCase().when(criteriaBuilder.equal(person.get("id"), id1), name_1);`

Comment: @KrantMin The server will go through each row only once for CASE expression, which is much better than having individual queries  getting executed for each condition.