# How to use CASE WHEN in Hibernate Where clause

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, hql

Plase give example for using `CASE WHEN` in HQL.

I have used following query in my code.

```
int receiptNumber = 100;
String hql = "SELECT b FROM OOPExtract as b "
                +"WHERE "
                +" b.tranStatId =" +receiptNumber+ " AND " 
                +" b.orderType IN ('EMERGENCY', 'PLENARY', 'PETITION','EXTENSION','MOTION') AND "
                +" CASE WHEN b.orderType == 'MOTION' " `enter code here`
                +  "THEN " 
                +" b.status = 'MOTION_SIGNED' " 
                +" ELSE " 
                +" b.status LIKE '%%'   " 
                +" END "        
                +" ORDER BY b.oopExtractId DESC";
```

But when it run it's generate following exception

> org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected token: = .....

Comment: Can refer here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/17588337/366964 similar one, might help.

Answer (score 2):

I've used the following query in a working project. Could use it as a template :)

```
"SELECT "
          + "CASE WHEN smth.status != 'BATMAN' THEN ... "
          + "ELSE (SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ... ORDER BY ... DESC limit 1) "
          + "END, "
          + "next_field, "
          + "CASE WHEN smth.status == 'BATMAN' THEN ... "
          + "ELSE ... "
          + "END, "
          + "final_field_which_doesent_have_a_case_logic"
          + "FROM ... the_rest_of_the_normal_query";
```

Answer (score 2):

This one works with Hibernate 4/JPA and Spring 4 as well!

```
select
    limite 
from
    Limite limite 
join
    fetch limite.limiteEnqs enq 
join
    fetch enq.limiteValors valor 
where
    limite.id      = :limiteId 
    and   :dataReferencia between valor.dtIniVig and valor.dtFimVig 
    and enq.vrAtributo1 = case limite.atributoId1 
        when 8 then :produtoId 
        else enq.vrAtributo1 
    end
```

Answer (score 0):

**Please try this. Hope it Work.**

```
            "SELECT b FROM OOPExtract as b WHERE "
            +" b.tranStatId =" +receiptNumber+ " AND " 
            +" b.orderType IN ('EMERGENCY', 'PLENARY', 'PETITION','EXTENSION','MOTION') AND "
            **+" CASE WHEN b.orderType 'MOTION' " `enter code here`
            +  "THEN 'MOTION_SIGNED' " 
            +" ELSE "** 
            +" b.status LIKE '%%'   " 
            +" END "        
            +" ORDER BY b.oopExtractId DESC";
```