# Batch Update by different values using Spring JPA/Hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

There is  Java entity class:

```
class Call {
   int callId,
   String callStatus
}
```

callStatus posibly values : SETUP, INSTALLED, FINISHED

And table *calls_statuses* has values

```
callId callStatus
1       SETUP
2       INSTALLED
3       INSTALLED
```

Then i need change statuses for callId 1 and 2 as :

```
1       INSTALLED
2       FINISHED
```

The call with callId 3 left same.

Is it possible to make a batch update using Spring JPA/Hibernate?

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this, a custom JPQL query would like:

```
    @Query("Update CallStatuses cs SET cs.callStatus = CASE WHEN (cs.callId IN :calls1) THEN :callStatusInstalled WHEN (cs.id IN :calls2) THEN :callStatusFinished END")
    batchUpdateCallStatus(@Param("calls1")List<int> calls1,
                          @Param("calls2") List<int> calls2,
                          @Param("callStatusInstalled") String callStatusInstalled, 
                          @Param("callStatusFinished") String callStatusFinished);
```

Posssible duplicate: [JPQL - Update with Multiple where conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17581840/jpql-update-with-multiple-where-conditions)